# Smart Groups Not an Option after Upgrade

Tags: wordpress, contacts, groups, smartgroups

We recently upgraded our Wordpress 4.7.1 installation to CiviCRM 4.7.15. I went to make a smart group today and noticed the option was not available. I previously added people to smart groups by going to **Report**> **Membership** > Select Approriate Report and results > **Action** > **Add to Smart Group**

When I got to Action now on the left there is no Add to Smart Group.

When I got **Contacts** > **Manage Groups** > I see the Smart Groups, but can't create a new smart group. I can create a regular ole managed group though.

Did something change?

Comment: If you want to know if it is something specific to your installation of maybe something more general, you can try to reproduce the situation on the demo installation on http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ .

Answer (score 5):

A smart group is a stored search. To create one a search is the starting point.

1. Do a search.
2. Opt for all records
3. Use the action "Create Smart Group".

In order to make a smart group selecting contacts that have a membership, you can start with an advanced search.

For example - Go to *Search -> Advanced Search*. Expand the membership section (this takes a bit of scrolling, in the illustration below I closed the other sections):

[image: Example Advanced Search]

Add the selection criteria (in the example Lifetime membership and Current Member). Execute the Search, do select all results and select the Create Smart Groep Option. Below an example of the Create Smart Group screen with criteria:
[image]

Comment: That is no longer an option. It was in the past but with the most recent upgrade it is not available.

Comment: The suggested edit is not correct, as it is not relevant to my actual question. I demonstrated that I know how to create a group in my question. However, that option is no longer available after upgrading.

Comment: Hi, @Tiffany, I just did a test on the sandbox instance, and it works (See http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org). The strategy, however, is not to use the Membership report but the advanced search option. I will update the answer to make it more clear.